# Receiving UDP from Dual NICs in Java & Ubuntu

Tags: java, ubuntu, networking, udp, broadcast

I have **2** UDP **broadcast** servers at 192.168.1.1 broadcasting to **192.168.1.255:1234** and at 192.168.2.1 broadcasting to **192.168.2.255:1235**.
I have a client that must receive all packets.
here is a simple code in **java**:

```
final DatagramSocket socket1, socket2;
    socket1 = new DatagramSocket(1234);
    socket2 = new DatagramSocket(1235);
    final DatagramPacket p = new DatagramPacket(new byte[10], 10);
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            while (true) {
                try {
                    socket1.receive(p);
                    System.out.println(p.getAddress());
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }).start();
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            while (true) {
                try {
                    socket2.receive(p);
                    System.out.println();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }).start();
}
```

The problem is that the java application cannot receive from both NICs in **Ubuntu**. It always receives from 192.168.2.255 (eth1). All packets can be dumped using **wireshark**, but java cannot receive them.
Also when I use exactly the same java code in **TinyCore** distro, there is no problem receiving packets from both NICs.
*What's wrong with Java in Ubuntu?*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to bind to a specific address, you need to specify it:

```
socket1 = new DatagramSocket(1234, InetAddress.getByName("192.168.1.255"));
socket2 = new DatagramSocket(1235, InetAddress.getByName("192.168.2.255"));
```

Also, you shouldn't use the same DatagramPacket instance in both threads as the will definitely share the buffer, and in case of concurrent packets, the outcome is unpredictable.